# Java Swing. How to detect that other component/window moved above my component?

Tags: java, swing, window, listener, repaint

I have a Java program that visualizes fast changing data. I schedule `javax.swing.Timer` and call `repaint()` every 50 milliseconds. But this takes a lot of CPU. Therefore I started to record the dirty areas (where the data has actually changed during 50 ms), and then call `repaint(x, y, w, h);`, where arguments identify the dirty region that requires repainting. This resolved CPU issue, but causes to some glitches when another window/component hovers over this component.

I want to detect such cases, and call `repaint()` for the whole component. Is there a way to detect it?

(I don't attach SSCCE, because I assume it's a known problem, and because it's not easy to detach it from my code. But I can do it if required).

Answer (score 1):

> I want to detect such cases,

I don't know of any way to detect what area of a frame is being covered.

> and call repaint() for the whole component. Is there a way to detect it?

Maybe you can use a `WindowListener` and handle a `windowDeactivated()` event. When the window doesn't have focus there is a good possibility that some other window is being displayed over it.

Comment: Thanks, I already tried `WindowsListener`, but it doesn't provide required callbacks.

Answer (score 1):

What about instead of tracking the dirty areas yourself, override the `paintComponent()` method, and use the `getClipBounds()` method on the `Graphics` object which will notify you what area of your `Component` you need to repaint?

Comment: The getClipBounds() method returns the bounds of the component. It is not aware that the component is partially covered by another window.